# .NET Framework Windows XP error, Visual Studio Express

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks, windows-xp

I have a fairly basic Windows Form application that I'm building in Visual Studio Express (2013), and am trying to deploy it to a Windows XP machine.  I have retargeted the apllication to ".NET Framework 4" in the project properties "Application" tab.  Additionally, I have verified the "App.config" file states "v4.0" for the .NET Framework.

When I publish the application and try to install on the XP machine, I get the follow error;

> Prerequisite check for system component Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
>   (x86 and x64) failed with the following error message: "Installation
>   of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is not supported on this operating
>   system. Contact your application vendor."

I have verified that the XP machine does have .NET v4.0 installed. Below is the text contained in the install.log generated during the installation attempt.  It appears that are reference to both 4.0 and 4.5 .NET

> The following properties have been set: Property: [AdminUser] = true
>   {boolean} Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string} Property:
>   [NTProductType] = 1 {int} Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = Intel
>   {string} Property: [VersionNT] = 5.1.3 {version} Running checks for
>   package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
>   Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET
>   Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' Read string value '4.0.30319' Setting
>   value '4.0.30319 {string}' for property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion'
>   The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)': Property: [DotNet45Full_TargetVersion] =
>   4.0.30319 {string} Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' Result of running operator
>   'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
>   Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'
>   is 'Bypass' Running checks for command
>   'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' Result of running operator
>   'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite':
>   false Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on
>   property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion' and value '4.5.50709': false
>   Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and
>   value 'false': false Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on
>   property 'VersionNT' and value '6.0.0': true Result of checks for
>   command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' is 'Fail' 'Microsoft
>   .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Fail A prerequisite
>   failed for Package "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)"
>   Package failed with message "Installation of the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 4.5 is not supported on this operating system. Contact your
>   application vendor."

Any thoughts on how to resolve would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to resolve the .NET issue by right clicking on the project -> Properties -> Publish.  Then clicking on the Prerequisites button and unchecking the .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Now a new error.  Or more accurately, errorS.  Not sure how to quote in this comment, but the log contains;   *Activation of XYZ.application resulted in exception.  Following failure messages were detected: + Exception reading manifest file from XYZ.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.  + Manifest XML signature is not valid.  + SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.